# key authorisation test case by JSON.strongify in JMEter

Tags: json, authentication, jmeter

I testing authorisation in JMeter.
Authorisation is by key, who is send in JSON.stringify.
first is open connected by web socket,
next send is key in json format.

how is the best way to testing is? what test case could be?
i think set happy path, and next authentication failed and in this give 
1. missing key - what testing/ set this in jmeter ?
2.bad key - not exist - what set this in jmeter?

what could be addicted test case/?
what testing authentication in jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) in order to open the WebSocket connection and send your request payload. Note that WebSocket Samplers are not a part of official JMeter distribution, you will need to install them using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/). You need **WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch**

   [image: JMeter WebSocket Samplers Installation]
2. You can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to add a conditional check to server response and change expected result according to your test case.
3. With regards to possible test cases - you should stick to the functional requirements and make sure that all of them are covered. If you don't have explicit requirements you're limited only by your fantasy and the time you have to implement your test, several possible use cases could be: something very big, null, numeric, boolean, another JSON object, JSON array, malformed JSON, not sending anything (session timeout), etc.